# Request GPS Location when button is clicked

Tags: android

I want to make a prompt to a user to request GPS location and then get the location (lat,lng) .

Like this:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CC8P9RN7_pk/VPTwYyjt8kI/AAAAAAAABWw/A5cjqZc39hQ/s1600/Location%2BSettings%2BDialog.png

Comment: first get a google map API here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup and use it to get your current location.

Comment: you are not relating to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is all covered in the location awareness training provided by Google, available [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html).

In particular:

- [the prompt](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#prompt)
- [obtaining the location (current and updates)](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Answer (score 0):

The code for GPS enable prompt:

```
public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

What you want for current location (Like lat,long or google map).